# Is it possible to link one Jenkins job to another and establish an upstream/downstream relationship?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I need to spawn a variable number of jobs from one upstream job. 
AFAIK, there is no plugin that can do this. The closest one is MultiJob plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin). 
So I thought to create a build step that would use one of the Jenkins APIs (REST, groovy or jenkins-cli) to trigger those builds. 
However, if I do that, those builds become "detached" (meaning they do not have an upstream job)  and the main job has no linkage with those builds.

So it boils down to this: is it possible to start a job build and tell it who is its upstream?

Comment: What do you need from the upstream job: Artifacts? SVN revision? Workspace?

Answer (score 3):

There is [**Build Result Trigger**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) plugin. It is literally the inverse of **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**. Instead of triggering downstream jobs, like the latter does, the Build Result Trigger lets your "downstream" jobs watch/monitor the progress of an upstream job, and trigger based on that result.

This way, your "upstream" job is actually not aware of downstream jobs that are watching it.

Comment: Thanks, but I **do** need the upstream job to be aware of the children and it needs to wait until they all complete. Good to know, but not suitable for my problem.

Comment: Then what problem are you having triggering multiple downstream projects?

Comment: please see my most recent comment where I explain what is my problem and why using Groovy code does not completely solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Groovy Plugin.

It'll let you fire as many jobs as you want, and set the upstream cause.

**Code Example:** http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin#Groovyplugin-Retrievingparametersandtriggeringanotherbuild

```
job.scheduleBuild2(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction(params))
```

Answer (score 0):

A related post is here:
[How do I dynamically trigger downstream builds in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884166/how-do-i-dynamically-trigger-downstream-builds-in-jenkins)

However, from all the answers that I have read it's clear that using the Groovy/Java class **hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(currentBuild)** does achieve the goal of programmatically triggering another job, but it does not fully establish an *upstream/downstream relationship*.
When you examine the builds you do not see any upstream/downstream information. The only way to see those is to open the console output of each.