# how can I trigger a jenkins job after claim a failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins plugin, [claim plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin) can help to claim a failure job with reasons.

And with the latest version (2.6+), it is able to run a global groovy script to do some notification whenever a claim is changed

But how can I trigger another job in this script ? it shall pass important parameters like jenkins name, build number and failure reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got answer by myself, the claim plugin is hacked using post job action, so it could be done like trigger downstream job. See code sample below:

```
import hudson.model.*

def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('ClaimNotify')
def build = action.owner

def causeAction = new CauseAction(new Cause.UpstreamCause(build))

Hudson.instance.queue.schedule(job,0, causeAction)
```

You can pass parameter there as well or in downstream job to fetch it as well.

see similar question and solution in [how-do-i-dynamically-trigger-downstream-builds-in-jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884166/how-do-i-dynamically-trigger-downstream-builds-in-jenkins)

more information about `schedule` function, can check [jenkins javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.html)