# How to run first build after build history erased

Tags: jenkins

I created a job that eventually seem to work

So I decided to erase all the unsuccessful builds history with these lines that I passed to Script Console:

```
// change this variable to match the name of the job whose builds you want to delete
def jobName = "JOB_NAME_custom_binary"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)

job.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }
// uncomment these lines to reset the build number to 1
job.nextBuildNumber = 1
job.save()
```

It removed all build from history, but now if I try to run build (select job option "Build with parameters" --> tap "Build" button) nothing seem to happen (no build started) - just a screen like below

[image]

Did I break something with that script? Can I fix it somehow or only re-create the job?

Answer (score 1):

almost everything you see on UI exist as files on file system

under /var/jenkins_home/jobs/PATH_TO_YOUR_JOB

there you will find config.xml which represents job config

and `builds` folder with folders for each build. usually with log files from console and some additional files

if `builds`(can have different name because of pipeline type) folder is empty then you can not restore items which your removed

i created "test" job in root jenkins with 2 parameters and run it 2 times

```
# ls -la /var/jenkins_home/jobs/test/builds
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug  1 21:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug  1 21:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug  1 21:36 1
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug  1 21:36 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins    0 Aug  1 21:33 legacyIds
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  126 Aug  1 21:36 permalinks

# cat permalinks 
lastCompletedBuild 2
lastFailedBuild -1
lastStableBuild 2
lastSuccessfulBuild 2
lastUnstableBuild -1
lastUnsuccessfulBuild -1
```

test/builds/2$ cat build.xml

```
...
<parameters>
  <hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue>
    <name>user</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue>
  <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
    <name>ENV</name>
    <value>222222</value>
  </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
</parameters>

...
```

with saved parameters

after your script execution

```
cat permalinks 
lastCompletedBuild -1
lastFailedBuild -1
lastStableBuild -1
lastSuccessfulBuild -1
lastUnstableBuild -1
lastUnsuccessfulBuild -1
jenkins@fc67fb3fb752:~/jobs/test/builds$ ls -la 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug  1 21:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug  1 21:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins    0 Aug  1 21:33 legacyIds
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  129 Aug  1 21:45 permalinks
```

there are no build directories

---

your script removed ALL builds for job (you dont have condition if success in it)

should be something like

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.Result

// change this variable to match the name of the job whose builds you want to delete
def jobName = "JOB_NAME_custom_binary"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)

job.getBuilds().each { build -> 
    if (build.getResult() != Result.SUCCESS) {
        build.delete() 
    }
}
// depends on what you need you need to detect it by your needs.
// job.nextBuildNumber = 1
```

your post title differs to description... it's unclear what exactly you need

how to trigger build now button via groovy see this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24262800/6727228